# How to add IDE shortcuts for code snippets?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, keyboard-shortcuts

I have a code block say

```
if(xxxx)
{
//do something for xxx
}
else if(yyyy)
{
    //do something for yyyy
}
```

and want to add it for many cases(~50).
I don't want to type in

```
    if(xxxx)
    {
       //do something for xxx
    }
```

everytime.

Can I add a shortcut like , pressing xx + SPACE would replace 'xx' with

```
if(xxxx)
        {
           //do something for xxx
        }
```

and pressing 'yy + SPACE' would replace 'yy' with

```
else if(yyyy)
    {
        //do something for yyyy
    }
```

The code segments 'xxxx' represent expressions and I need to alter them for certain scenarios, so not looking for *Find and Replace* (or using Regex for that matter). Something on the lines of `sout` to `System.out.println()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create your own snippets following [this msdn article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165394(v=vs.120).aspx). There's more you *could* add to your snippet, but I'll outline the basics below.

First, create a file called MySample.snippet. *(the name of the file doesn't matter)*

Modify the title, shortcut and actual code as necessary.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CodeSnippets
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
    <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
        <Header>
            <Title>My xxxx Snippet</Title>
            <Shortcut>xx</Shortcut>
        </Header>
        <Snippet>
            <Code Language="CSharp">
                <![CDATA[if (xxxx)
{

}]]>
            </Code>
        </Snippet>
    </CodeSnippet>
</CodeSnippets>
```

To add your snippet to Visual Studio:

1. Go to Tools / Code Snippets Manager (or press Ctrl+B).
2. Select "Visual C#" from the drop-down.
3. Select "My Code Snippets"
4. Click the "Import" button and select your file.
5. Make sure "My Code Snippets" is selected on the right and press "Finish", then "OK.

Now, when you type "xx" and press <kbd>Tab</kbd>, it replaces "xx" with the code you specified. Repeat the process to create as many snippets as you need.

For versions of VS up to 2010, there's a tool on CodePlex called the [Snippet Editor](http://snippeteditor.codeplex.com/) that you may want to check out.

Answer (score 1):

Built in snippets come close. For example, if you type `if` followed by 2 tabs, it will highlight the condition, which should speed thing up for you.

It's also possible to write your own snippets and add them to `Documents\Visual Studio (version)\Code Snippets` (or use `Tools > Code Snippets Manager`).

Comment: The condition is an expression with multiple variables, also the block inside is not empty. I l update the question with more details.

Comment: Should still work. The built-in snippets are very general in nature, but you can easily copy one that's close and alter it to your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Look at Visual Studio code snippets: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165392.aspx